# How to add a custom property to a PowerShell array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, properties, pscustomobject

Say I have a PowerShell array `$Sessions = @()` which I am going to fill with PSCustomObjects. How can I add a custom property to the array itself? E.g. so I can have `$Sessions.Count` which is built-in and `$Sessions.Active` which I want to set to the active session count.

I know that I can add properties to PSCustomObjects (in a dirty way) with

```
$MyCustomObject = "" | Select-Object Machine, UserName, SessionTime
```

but though doing so on an array would not result in the property being added.

So how can I achieve my goal? Is there any way to create a custom array?

Comment: Just use `Add-Member -InputObject $sessions ...`? That is what it is for

Comment: Beware, though, that appending to that array (`$sessions += ...`) will replace the array, thus removing the additional property. A safer approach would be a custom object with distinct properties for array and state. With that said, depending on what you want to use this for it might be more appropriate to use different list variables `$activeSessions`/`$inactiveSessions` instead of adding a property to the list, or to add an `Active` property to the individual session objects.

Comment: @Matt if you only would've postet as an answer... I actually abused `Select-Object` out of laziness which was what kept me from my solution. Thanks.

@AnsgarWiechers thanks for the hint about `+=`, saved me from misplacing the `Add-Member` call.

Comment: I forgot to mention the `Select` you did is a perfectly acceptable method of creating a blank slate object. To each there own in this regard. The only setback from your method is in how basic it can be for things like types and complex properties. Still nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to your question as stated would be to just use `Add-Member` on the array object.

```
Add-Member -InputObject $sessions -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "State" -Value "Fabulous"
```

Adding a property to each element *after you created the object* is similar.

```
$sessions | ForEach-Object{
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "State" -Value "Fabulous"
}
```

This of course comes with a warning (that I forgot about). From comments

> Beware, though, that appending to that array ($sessions += ...) will replace the array, thus removing the additional property.
>
> <sup>[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers)</sup>

Depending on your use case there are other options to get you want you want. You can save array elements into distinct variables:

```
# Check the current object state
$state = $object.Property .....

# Add to the appropriate array.
if($state -eq "Active"){
    $activeSessions += $object
} else {
    $inactiveSessions += $object
}
```

Or you could still store your state property and post process with `Where-Object` as required:

```
# Process each inactive session
$sessions | Where-Object{$_.State -eq "Active"} | ForEach-Object{}
```

To avoid the destroying / recreating array issue, which can be a performance hog, you could also use an array list instead.

```
$myArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Add-Member -InputObject $myArray -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "NeverTellMeTheOdds" -Value {
    $this | Where-Object{$_ % 2 -ne 0}
}

$myArray.AddRange(1..10)
$myArray.NeverTellMeTheOdds()
```

Notice that the array had its member added then we added its elements.

Answer (score 3):

As Matt commented, you can use the `Add-Member` on an enumerable type by supplying it as a positional argument to the `-InputObject` parameter.

To allow for resizing after adding the new property, use a generic `List` instead of `@()`:

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new()
$list.AddRange(@(
  [pscustomobject]@{SessionId = 1; Active = $true}
  [pscustomobject]@{SessionId = 2; Active = $false}
  [pscustomobject]@{SessionId = 3; Active = $true}
) -as [psobject[]])

Add-Member -InputObject $list -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name ActiveSessionCount -Value {
  return @($this |? Active -eq $true).Count
}
```

Now you can retrieve the active session count easily:

```
PS C:\> $list.ActiveSessionCount
2
```

Comment: I suggested an arraylist. We think alike it seems.